# Is "head hunter's frequently asked questions list" good idea?

Tags: employer-relations

I have created list of 10 most frequently asked questions by head hunters.
So for some time, when I was asked for one of them I just copy-pasted answer from pdf, and this worked quite well, but sometimes I had to change words a little to better fir in context.

Then, I have started sending this pdf along with cv.
This is the moment, when I have noticed very big drop in response rate.
When copy-pasting answers I had around 4 replies per 5 send mails, but when attaching pdf's it's like 1 in 10.

Why is that?
Isn't it handy for head hunter to have all answers at once?
Do they feel offended or something?
All answers are the same as I was copy-pasting.

EDIT:
I am experienced software programmer and I nearly always fulfill 100% of job requirements.

- The biggest problem is: I am studying two degrees at once, so I can
  take only part job and they want to employ me on full-time job.
- Second most frequent question is: if I want to migrate to other country to
  work, which I don't.
- Third one is about cash, I prefer to tell them how much I want in
  first mail, so we won't waste time if they cannot afford.
- Forth question is: when can I start, which is one month.
- Fifth is that I do programming test only if they pay for it.
- Sixth is that I do not provide telephone number, I don't tell them why, but
  I simply don't want to talk with them during my lectures, and they
  ring just then.
- Seventh is when I can meet with them, that happens to be in 3 weeks.

Sample rate is:

40 out of 50 responded, when not attaching pdf

1 out of 10 responded when attached.

EDIT 2:

I have done one more approach - instead of sending pdf, I have moved all answers into html template, that I have sent to around 10 employers.
After one day I got back 5 replies.

EDIT 3:
I would like to thank You all who answered or commented on this question - I believe I have learned a little from each and everyone of You.
Frankly, I would like to accept at least half of those answers, but Stack Overflow limits me to one.

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: Why are you even contacting headhunters yourself? And why so many?

Comment: WorkerDrone which part? Sending FAQ causes drop in response rate, while answering one-by-one doesn't - I am asking why.
@Lilienthal I just reply to job offers, I do not know who reads it (head hunter or employer). Why so many? So I have a choice of course.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the women I try to sleep with. When they come back to my place, I give them a pre-packaged travel bag with their own toothbrush and mini-sized toothpaste. In my fridge, they can see that I have a dozen champagne bottles in there. And when I give them a red rose and tell them how special they are, they will take a peek into the room to see where I've pulled the rose out of -- only to find 20 red roses individually wrapped. After that, the night doesn't go well at all. I don't understand. Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong? Normally roses work!

Comment: @StephanBranczyk LOL... couldn't have said better myself :)

Comment: @StephanBranczyk so You think, that head hunters just want to feel special, but frankly I do not think this is it, as even before attaching pdf I was saying, that I can meet with employer no faster than in 3 weeks as I have other meetings, and there was no problem - they were still replying till we agreed on some point in time.

Comment: To be honest, I question your sample size. Either it's too small to make a meaningful conclusion, or you're applying to so many jobs that you are likely unqualified for a number of them. I'd suggest rephrasing this to ask if it's a good idea to attach "answers to common questions" to your application.

Comment: see my edit in question

Comment: "Feel special" is the wrong word. But I have a question for you, do you really email your resume to 40 to 50 headhunters? You don't try to contact employers directly? For the phone number, you should try to provide a google voice phone number, or a free equivalent in your country.

Comment: Yes, I really email 50 employers, I have script to do it. What do You mean to contact employer directly? Phone cost isn't issue here, I just don't want be disturbed during lectures.

Comment: "Yes, I really email 50 employers, I have script to do it" - I can't help but feel that your approach is going to make you look, basically, like a spammer. And that doesn't sound like a good way of getting results. Also, your answer to question 1 will rule you out of the vast majority of opportunities, and your answers to questions 5, 6 and 7 all make you seem extremely difficult to work with.

Comment: After reading your edit, I am more convinced of my position.  You are coming across as pushy and rude.  This may not be your intent, but given the vehemence with which you reject the advice below, the assumption may not be far off base.

Comment: @xinus01, "40 out of 50 responded, when not attaching pdf. 1 out of 10 responded when attached." But how many of the 80% who respond without the PDF attached remain interested after you answer their "FAQ" questions? That's the important number. If it's around 5, then one could argue that your technique *is* working, and is simply weeding out the headhunters for whom you don't meet the criteria.

Comment: To not be bothered during lectures, turn the phone of our set it to silent and let the call go to voicemail or let them call back. Trivial technological solution.

Comment: 1) You sound incredibly entitled and rude. If the language or  tone you use here is even close to how you correspond with employers, good luck being taken seriously. 2) There are few remote-only jobs. Very few international remote jobs. Almost none that are part-time. 3) Point 5, 6 and 7 instantly disqualify you for most hiring processes.

Comment: 1. It's only because I am brutally honest with You. I am not opening so much on hiring process. 2. Frankly, I just want job for holidays, but if I tell them about it they won't hire me. 3. Point 5 is only about 5% or employers, so they can be ignored, as I save around 3-4h on this decision. Point 7 is just result of many planned interviews, so this restriction naturally softens with time. And about point 6 - You are 100% right here, but this was the reason for creating list like that.

Comment: You know the saying "death by a thousand cuts", in your case it should be called "unemployment by a thousand cuts".  Following on what Lilienthal said, I'd recommend you have an English native speaker proofread anything you send out to recruiters for spelling, grammar, tone, and professionalism.  And if you only want to work during the holidays, work driving for Uber, or work for TaskRabbit. Getting a temporary job during the holidays is usually not a problem. And it really doesn't take any kind of preparation to get one of those jobs. It just takes a little bit of humility and that's it.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I believe, that You misunderstood my intentions - we are not speaking here about unemployment - I'm earning double average of my country. My intention is to continuously change jobs for better salary. However, I also have quite high expectations, so I want to reply to as much job offers that I would like to do, from there drop those offers, that do not meet my requirements, and from remaining set pick one, that offers most cash. I certainly won't work for Uber, because I would earn around third of what I earn now plus I would not learn much in terms of IT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an old joke: A guy goes to a doctor. He says, "Doctor, every time I twist my arm behind my back like this, I get a sharp pain in my shoulder." And the doctor replies, "So stop twisting your arm behind your back like that."

If including this file with your resume is hurting your response rate, then stop including it!

That said, I think the bigger question is whether the idea of sending a "here are my responses to questions I get asked a lot" with your resume is a fundamentally bad idea, or whether the problem is the specific answers you gave.

I don't see a problem with the basic idea. I've been involved in hiring people a number of times, and while I don't recall ever getting such a list, I can't imagine why it would turn me against the applicant. Indeed, as it's unusual, it would probably catch my attention. And when an employer gets a ton of resumes, anything that makes yours stand out is good. (Well, not if it stands out in an obviously negative way, but you know what I mean.)

I'd look at the answers you're giving. I suspect that one or more of your specific answers is raising alarms with potential employers.

Or, of course, the decline in your response rate could be coincidence. I've applied for a lot of jobs in my life, and a 4 out of 5 response rate seems very good. I had one time I got a 100% response rate, but that's because I contacted one company and they hired me the next day. I haven't kept statistics but I'd guess that normally I've gotten less than a 10% response rate.

** Update ***

Wait, I may have misread the question.

The question starts out with OP saying that he sends this FAQ with his resume. But then he says he sends the FAQ instead of cutting and pasting responses to specific questions.

If you apply for a job based on ad ad somewhere, and send this FAQ with your resume, I'd think that's a perfectly good thing to do. Though see RichardU's comments below.

But if you send in a resume, and the employer then responds with an email asking questions, and instead of directly answering their questions, you reply to the email by sending this generic FAQ, I'd say that's a bad idea. It tells the employer, I don't care enough about this position to actually read your questions and answer them, so I'll just send this generic FAQ. Even if all the employer's questions are covered in the FAQ, it looks like you don't care.

If you don't mean that the employer sent you a personal email asking these questions, where do the questions come from? Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: No matter how bad my answers are, when I get asked them one-by-one answers remains the same, so I guess it's just idea of attaching A4 pdf with FAQ. So the question is - is generally pre answering questions bad or form (pdf) or amount of text (A4)?

Comment: The idea of' "pre-answering" questions seems like a good one to me. If your sure it's not the specific answers, I suppose there could be something about the PDF itself that turns employers off -- particularly clumsy formatting, or so long that they say "hey I'm not reading all this, forget it", or ... something. Without more details, I can't say. You might try tinkering with it. But in the long run, if it's hurting you, dump it.

Comment: @Jay it comes across as pushy and difficult and unwilling to follow directions and/or guidance.  NEXT CANDIDATE.

Comment: @RichardU Hmm, maybe I'm missing something. If an employer publishes some sort of ad asking for applications, and someone sends a resume with such an attachment, I don't see how that would be "not following instructions". Unless the ad specifically said, "Don't include any attachments with your resume." Now if an employer sent a questionnaire, and instead of answering their questions, you sent a canned "here are my responses to common questions", I could see that being a problem. Like, "oh, he can't be bothered to answer our questions".

Comment: The joke, imho, works better as "Doctor, it hurts when I do that". "Well don't do that".

Comment: @LaconicDroid Too fast. You need to build a little suspense. But hence your handle, I guess.

Comment: @Jay The expected attachments are a cover letter and references if asked.  Even including unsolicited references might get a raised eyebrow.

Comment: @RichardU Well, from the fact that he's getting negative results, you may be right. When I've been involved in hiring, I certainly wouldn't have penalized someone for supplying extra information like that. But then I'm not an HR person.

Comment: @Jay I'm not an HR person either, but I've dealt with them for years and I won't repeat what I think of them in polite company.  I can say that they don't like things that don't fit into neat little piles.  A strange PDF like that would just annoy them.  What's important to remember is that it's not what you, I, or the OP think is a good idea, it's what HR wants to see.  The only exception would be a startup or small company that doesn't have an HR dept, or headhunters that just don't care about personal relationships.

Comment: @Jay I have been trying both approaches - sending FAQ along with CV and then sending it as reply - both have same negative result.

Answer (score 12):

What you are doing is extremely impersonal and puts workload from yourself onto the headhunter.  This alienates from the good ones and bad ones both.  The good ones want to build a relationship with you and sending them a canned response can show that you are not interested.  The bad ones don't want to spend 2 minutes reading the response.  If they can't get their answers in ten seconds they feel they are wasting their time.

Maybe this is dropping your response rate but my impression is that if you think this is a good idea then this type of activity discourages recruiters you wouldn't work well with.

Edit:
Comment from OP

> You are seconds person that says about "relationship" especially in
>   context of head hunter, and then immediately about their time shortage
>   - this two things just do not go along. Let's be honest, I do not want any relationship with head hunter, and head hunter don't want
>   relationship with me - I want job, and he wants finder's fee.

The "good" ones care about offering you good service and not wasting your time so you will come back to them when you are looking for your next job. By coming back impersonal you are showing them this effort is wasted, so you don't fit their business model very well. The bad ones just care about how many applicants per hour they can throw at openings and have no interest repeat clients. By making more minutes of work for them you are wasting their time and don't fit their business model.

Comment: You are seconds person that says about "relationship" especially in context of head hunter, and then immediately about their time shortage - this two things just do not go along. Let's be honest, I do not want any relationship with head hunter, and head hunter don't want relationship with me - I want job, and he wants finder's fee.

Comment: "I want job, and he wants finder's fee" - sounds like a good approach to take if you want to ensure that you only ever work with crappy recruiters. I've dealt with plenty that would love to work on a basis like that - only problem is, they're the ones I never want to deal with again.

Comment: "puts workload from yourself onto the headhunter" Isn't that their job?

Comment: @Kevin For the good ones this isn't a problem.  For the bad ones who are just about firing off X number of applications per day regardless of fit, adding a couple minutes to the process makes you undesirable.

Comment: I really do not understand this idea of dividing into categories like "good head hunter", "bad head hunter", "employer himself". In any case I do not know to whom I am sending CV, and in any case I do not care - I will get job or not. How can I benefit from "good head hunter" after getting a job?

Comment: @xinus01 They show understanding of your requirements/limitations and get you interviews for positions that fit well.  You get a great job.  The continued benefit is in a couple of years when you are looking for your next gig or looking to hire reports, you work with them again since they do a more efficient job than the competition.

Comment: I remember, when I have applied for one job through two head hunters from same company. One replied that they require telephone number and rejected me, while second offered interview. After 3 months I have been applying for other job through same head hunters, and first one accepted me even without phone number. I can safety assume, that they didn't remember me. With same logic I could spend hour with person that sold me car, because maybe in 5-10 years I will buy next car from him.

Comment: @xinus01 Then go with headhunters that will throw you every opening under the sun without consideration as to whether you actually qualify.  You've been shown why your strategy is flawed for headhunters who are trying for a relationship and those who are trying for a transaction only.  Accept an answer or offer a better answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

It just means, you don't care to answer their questions personally but expecting them to hunt and peck among the stuff you put in a page, thinking they will all need that information.

Revert the tables and think how you feel when you get a canned response email from one of the companies you have a relationship with and asking them a question which is important to you? Well, they feel the same way when you send them everything including the kitchen sink, while they are asking for a small portion of this information.

It is the establishment of a relationship, not a volume game.

Comment: I have actually thought about it this way, but employers and head hunters do send pdf's with described job offers this way, and no future employee feels bad about it.

Comment: Recruiters (who are not on top of my favorite people list) play the numbers game. They throw as many balls to the wall as they can, using their handy dandy software, mostly from India, for us, US based potential employees in IT field, just by a keyword match. They do not care if you are actually fit for the job. They basically expect you to eliminate yourself by not responding. If you respond with a general form letter, they do not have time to read it because it takes away from their numbers game. This is the gist of it. My original answer was for recuiters who has genuine interest in you

Comment: You say "they don't have time to read this", but if I won't send them full list at once, but answer them one-by-one it will take much more time.
I am not drawing like between head hunters and employers in this question, as I simply reply to job offer and I do not know who reads it.
They just have to ask few standard questions, I am just trying to save out mutual time.

Comment: For the ones that are gebnuinely interested in you, you are alienating them by effectively telling them "I do not have time to answer your questions personally", which is basically offending them. The others, i.e. the pond-scum of recruitment industry, would not even consider reading a page full of answers to see if what they need is in that page. They want to see **"_Java development: 5 years_"** and two or three more lines like this. If you give them 50 lines, they skip your answers

Comment: So You hold that there is no problem in sending answers before questions, but amount of text to read is what scares them? So solution is to shrink answers to 5-10 lines and attach to email as text?

Comment: Again the same concept. If you want the Indian recruiter wanna-be's to respond to you, you need to send them **exactly** what they ask you. Otherwise they do not comprehend the content. These people follow a playbook. If you are out of that book, you are done and gone. But you really do not want to work with those because they do not have any relationship with the people who are going to hire you. They are just after their finder's fee. It is like spam email 1 million viagra ad emails, cosr 10 cents to send if one person responds, you made you investment thousand times over with commission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40241/discussion-between-xinus01-and-melburslan).

Answer (score 4):

If by some magic you got past a recruiter and my HR department and I received your paperwork, I would pop it in my discard pile for a very simple reason:

- Cannot follow simple instructions

Even before we get to any qualifications, if you can't do as asked specifically, and provide results in the format requested, then why should I think you can follow more complex instructions?

I'f I'm looking through 100 CV's for 1 or 2 positions, I am going to use anything that lets me cull from my pile of paper, as I don't have time to spend 15 minutes on each CV. I will cull all that are badly formatted, or have silly spelling mistakes, or are unreadable, or appear to be a pre-written boilerplate (which is what you are sending out)

Boilerplate shows me you are not personally invested in getting this role. I will want to hire people who have researched my roles, and my company, and can demonstrate they want it, not someone who has sent out 50 CV's hoping any of them work.

Comment: How is pre-answering or sending bulk answers not following simple instructions? They didn't instruct me anything (yet?).

Comment: @xinus01 the key is that they asked you to answer specific questions in a specific order and a specific way; those are their instructions. Not doing so comes across as extreme arrogance at best and inability to follow the simplest instructions at worst.

Answer (score 2):

A resume/CV is like a movie trailer.  The point is to generate interest in the movie, not reveal the entire plot.

What you are doing by sending the PDF is revealing the entire plot.  Now they feel they've seen the entire movie and don't need anything else from you.  What they are likely feeling towards you is the same feeling you'd get if you saw a trailer and felt you've seen the entire movie: cheated.

They are, after all, headhunters and it is their job to ask questions.  By pre-empting them, you're not coming across as helpful, you're coming across as trying to do their job for them.

Go back to your original strategy and be prepared for questions, but never **ever** answer them in advance.

Comment: I cannot agree that they "don't need anything else from" me after answering all their questions - their job is to deliver employee, which they don't. Also, wouldn't You like to someone else simplify and speed up Your job?

Comment: @xinus01 I repeat, you're coming across as trying to do their job for them, as well as pushy, and quite frankly, rude.  THAT translates as being a potential headache should they send you on an interview.  So, they will pass you over for someone who seems less problematic.

Comment: How is simplifying and speeding up their job pushy and rude? If You are selling car, and I am trying to buy it, then I WILL ask for price, who rode it etc - why won't You just tell me about it at the beginning? Would that be pushy and rude?

Comment: @xinus01 My own observation of you is that you are in fact acting in an unprofessional manner.  You are convinced that your way is the right way and disregard any opinions offered, ignoring what is said and instead reiterating your position.  There is a distinct and significant difference between being eager and being pushy.  Asking if someone has any questions is being eager.  Providing a list of prepared answers is pushy.  It is also impersonal.  Ignore the advice being given to you at your own peril.  We have some very experienced and accomplished people here and you are trying our patience

Comment: I am not ignoring Your advices, I am just trying to confront them with my point of view. I can always get back to answering questions one-by-one, so this is not a problem. I want to learn, how can I automatize my process with minimal to no loss of reply rate in context of "being rude or nonprofessional".

Comment: xinus01 - it may well be your point of view, but you already have the evidence that it really doesn't work. So...accept that your point of view is wrong, and understand what others actually do want from a candidate.

Comment: If he doesn't reveal that he is only available part time or is not willing to relocate, and they email back and forth couple of times or even gets invited to talk and then find out it is not a good fit - how is that better? It wastes both their time. I agree there is probably something wrong with how he is doing this - the idea per is pretty cool though (and I don't understand why the question was closed). Doesn't seem rude either, maybe it was edited away ...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a good idea (imo, obviously).

You are a programmer, they are not and a FAQ is not something they are used to: they are evaluating people and not evaluating the features of a software that can be explained in a FAQ on the vendor's website.
Also writing down cash in a checklist is something that feels 'rude' to me (but that's me, is something I dislike badly and prefer to discuss face to face). The same for the programming test: your position is understandable but leave money out of the first contact.

What you can do is attach a cover letter to your submission with the very same content in a written text:

> Dear sirs,
>  here is my cv for position XXX.
> Please understand that
>   studying 2 degrees at once I'm looking for part jobs only in my
>   area/country.
> Because of the above I'm available for a
>   meeting/interview in X weeks and could start in Y months.
>   For any contact please use my email address: should you need a phone contact let me know your number and I'll call you back as soon as possible.
>   Best regards

Comment: About money - if I would not include it, I would have like 10x more interviews, however, after passing them I would have to decline 90% of them, so in the end I would waste HUGE amount of time. I remember one job offer like that, I came to interview and answered everything 100% correctly. They rang (yep, I was providing phone number back then) hour ago and said I got the job, and we just need to talk about money and hours. I was so much shocked, when they have offered like 70% of what I was earning back then. I have immediately get out, and I am getting furious whenever I think about it...

Comment: As for programming tests - it takes few hours each. I can easily get a job without such a waste. I know that they won't pay me for doing interview test, so this is just my most pleasant way of telling "You must be out of Your mind, if You think that I will do anything for free". Jobs with programming tests are like 3 per 60, so around 5%, they can be ignored without problem.

Also, I have tried Your idea of shortening it into text (see my edit in question) and it turned quite well, thank You.

Comment: If you turn down 90% of the offers because of the money, maybe your bar is too high or you target the wrong ads... 90% is a huge number

Comment: I don't need these 90% employers, I just need one that meets my expectations. About my bar - I am continuously pushing it up, so it's obvious that I will eventually hit cap, and this is my point - to work for as much money, that no one offers me more. And about wrong targets - it's very hard to pick right ones, especially with head hunters involved. For same job level I have seen offers with cash in range 8-12k (spacial case of facebook group that requires to provide cash offer). Only general rule is bigger company = bigger cash. This is also whole point of "spamming" and automatizing.

Comment: you didn't get it: if your expected salary is higher than the actual cap for the position you apply for, nobody will ever consider your cv. you can push as much as you like but the market is the limit. ask for a salary above the max and your cv will be dumped in no time.

Comment: you need the head hunters because they link you to the employer of your dreams. imho you should revise your way of dealing with other people because all your comments are on the line 'I want and they must': it does not work this way.

Comment: If 10% employers offer as much as I want, then this is market price for me. I am eager to hit the cap, because if I do, it means, I earn as much as possible - this is the goal. I am not dealing in way "I want - they must", I simply do not agree to classic scheme that is: employee begs for work and Almighty employer decides about life and death. If there are 10 employers, and 9 of them offer $X and 1 offers $X+1, then I want to dump those 9 as fast as possible, and talk only with the remaining one.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend a lot on your list of FAQ's and your answer to those questions.  My tips for creating an FAQ to submit would be:

- For the most part limit your FAQ to Yes or No questions or questions that can be answered in 3 or 4 words.

When skimming a resume I do not want to read and reread answers to understand them.  But short answers are fine and can help me make sure you fit the basics of the position.

- Avoid questions that may make you be perceived as a negative person.

Most of the questions you include should be answered yes.  A few no's in the middle are fine but If I look at your list of questions and it reads no, no, no, no...  I agree you are a no, even though I may have never even read the questions.

- Make sure the questions are ones that most employers want to know.

If the list of questions is irrelevant then I am going to wonder if your communication skills are lacking or if your decision making abilities are impaired.  Neither answer helps you.  So make sure your questions are worth including.

It is also entirely possible that you are skipping the initial filters by providing them the information they need.  If you are contacted by 9 recruiters and 8 of the jobs that are not a good match for you, vs the one that is a potential good match then your FAQ is doing its job.

Comment: I have added FAQ in my edit in original question.
I have been thinking about not including "negative" answers, but truth is, they will ask them anyway, and I will tell them "negative" truth.